# get 2d generic matrix iterator

Tags: java, generics, matrix, iterator

I am trying to make an 2d matrix that can hold different objects, mainly int and String. So far I have managed to store values correctly(some how), but I have no idea how to make an Iterator out of an 2d matrix containing T values, so it works in the test2 method below.

```
public class Matrix<T> implements Iterable<T>  {

    private T[][] matrix;

    public Matrix(int rows, int columns) {

    this.rows = rows;
    this.columns = columns;

    matrix = (T[][]) new String[rows][columns];
    }

    public void insert(int row, int column, T value) {
    matrix[row][column] = (T) value;        
    }
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> matrixList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    ArrayList<?> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(matrix[0][0]));

        return (Iterator<T>) (a.iterator());
    }
}
```

It is suppose to be the answer to this test in the test2 method:

```
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        Matrix<String> m = new Matrix<String>(2, 2);

        m.insert(0, 0, "a");
        m.insert(0, 1, "b");
        m.insert(1, 0, "c");
        m.insert(1, 1, "d");

    for (String element : m) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

So far it only prints the value in the matrix i chose(in this case "a"). I want to make it print all values in the matrix. 
If i

> ArrayList a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(matrix));
>   It says: 
>   lJava.lang.String cannot be cast to Java.lang.String.

Be gentle, but honest, I am a noob <3
I hope someone has the answer, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding only element on 0,0 index in your `Iterator`. Rewrite you `Iterator` like this:

```
public Iterator<T> iterator() {

    ArrayList<T> a = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        Collections.addAll(a, matrix[i]);
    }
    return (Iterator<T>) (a.iterator());
}
```

And it should work.

Comment: Omg, I have tried several hours to solve this.. why could I not get this?! Thank you so very much tho!